# Is it common for the name Dimitri to be written as ドミトリ?

Tags: word-choice

If some of you might be familiar with Resident Evil Village, there is a character called Alcina Dimitrescu, her last name being Romanian and in Japanese it is written as ドミトレスク which sounds like DOMITORESUKU.
There have been discussions regarding the pronunciation of this character's name, because, as a Romanian, I can tell you that in English that's not the actual pronunciation of the name, but regarding the Japanese spelling and pronunciation, I have also seen Japanese users on Twitter asking why isn't the name written like **ディミトレスク** because I know characters called Dimitri and it's written ディミトリand pronounced DI.

I've seen people on social media who talked about this subject saying "Japanese people can't pronounce the "di" sound, that's why they changed it or else the name would have been Jimitoresuku!" 
 That statement was horrible...
 I just want to know if the ドミトレスク spelling for the name Dimitri is common. By the way, in Romanian we do not have DOmitrescu, actually the most common version of the name is DUmitrescu, with Dimitrescu being the other version that's usually heard.

Answer (score 1):

Weblio E-J / J-E has decent coverage for various things, including names.  [Their entry for *Dimitri*](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/Dimitri) shows ドミトリー as one rendering.

I suspect this initial ド arose due to influence from common Russian-derived name Dmitri ([Weblio entry here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/Dmitri)), without any explicit vowel between the initial "D" and the following "m".  In such cases, the "default" vowel for a kana rendering would become the "o" (the back close vowel that still allows for initial //d//, and also for an easy shift to that following //m//), giving us the initial ド in the katakana.

Comment: I thought that since it was not spelled Dmitri, then it could have been  ディミトリ because Dimitrescu has the I between D and M.

Comment: @AliceB.Rabbit, words can influence other words in interesting ways.  I suspect the Russian-derived spelling might have been more familiar to Japanese readers, not least as Russia is literally right next door, whereas Romania isn't all that close.